# Text_format field value not retained in form

Tags: 7, forms, wysiwyg, chaos-tool-suite

I am using Ctools to generate a popup and I'm loading my form inside it. In order to use a textfield with youtube link embedding and image uploading, I am using WYSIWYG module with CKeditor library.

My problem is that, when I define a form field with **text_format** as type, the values that are given in the field are not retained in the `$form_state` or `$form` variables.

I checked by defining the default value, It seems to be retained in the form_state['values'] but any changes that are done to the default value in the rendered form is not reflected.

```
$form['optional_links'] = array(
    // '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#format' => 'plain_text',
    '#default_value' => 'unique',
    '#title' => t('Optional: include additional info like link or image that gives context'),
  );
```

The same form works perfectly with **textfield** type. I even tried changing the formats but of no use.

Comment: Had anyone faced this problem?